# Store and get location in radius on MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, gps, bing-maps

I am creating an application for the Windows 10 using C#.
This application stores a number of locations on a MySQL database and shows to the users the locations stored by other users that are near him(by a given radius).

I wanted to know the best way to both store and retrieve this locations. I thought about retrieving all the locations and checking if they are inside the radius by code, but maybe for a lot of entries on the database this can became too inneficient.

Is there any MySQL function that could filter this?

Comment: If you have a lot of locations in that database, use one that has the possibility to store spatial data and create a spatial index over it. I don't know if MySQL has that capability, I know SQL Server has. You'll need to store your locations as geometry objects of course, for the spatial index to work. Do not store latitude and longitude in separate columns, there is no way to index that efficiently for large amounts of two-dimensional data. The geometry data type will have a function that calculates the distance between two point geometries. Use it.

Comment: To be precise, in SQL Server a geometry exists in a flat surface. If you use logintude and latitude, you actually need a geography object. For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx. MySQL may have something equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought about retrieving all the locations and checking if they are inside the radius by code

You *definitely* don't want to go down that road.  Always fetching every record and filtering it yourself in code is bad for a multitude of reasons, not the least of which being performance.

Relational databases are really good at querying data, it's mostly a matter of defining that query and how to store the data to be queried in the way you need it.  In this case, if I'm understanding you correctly, what you want is:

> Store a list of geographical locations and, given a point on a map, return a list of known points within a given radius.

The first thing you want to make sure you're doing is storing the latitude and longitude of the locations.  All meaningful calculations are going to be based off of that.  Once you have that, the rest is math.

Now, full disclosure, it's been [a *long* time](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2011/02/shortest-distance-between-two-points-is.html) since I've used this.  And it never actually went into production, so I don't know if the calculations are *entirely* accurate.  (This might have a bug somewhere is what I'm saying.)  But, given a table of locations, something like this should retrieve the locations around a point sorted by distance from that point:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Address,
  City,
  State,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  (
    ACOS(
      COS(@center_latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(@center_longitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(Latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(Longitude * (PI()/180)) +
      COS(@center_latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      SIN(@center_longitude * (PI()/180)) *
      COS(Latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      SIN(Longitude * (PI()/180)) +
      SIN(@center_latitude * (PI()/180)) *
      SIN(Latitude * (PI()/180))
    ) *
    (
      (@equatorial_radius * @polar_radius) /
      (
        SQRT(
          (@equatorial_radius * @equatorial_radius) -
          (
            (
              (@equatorial_radius * @equatorial_radius) -
              (@polar_radius * @polar_radius)
            ) *
            (
              COS(@center_latitude) *
              COS(@center_latitude)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ) AS Miles
FROM
  Places
WHERE
  Miles <= @search_radius
```

This query accepts a center lat/long and a radius (the distance from the location to search) and finds any known locations within that distance from the center and notes that distance in miles (so we can sort and find the closest).  You can use any measurement you want (kilometers, meters, etc.) as long as you consistently use the same one throughout the calculations.

It also accepts parameters for the radius of the Earth. These can be hard-coded if you want instead of parameterized.  Originally I had used these:

```
@equatorial_radius = 3963.190 miles
@polar_radius = 3949.902 miles
```

(Note that this equatorial radius is pretty old and may not account for the crust displacement during the 2004 Indian Ocean earthquake or any other major events since then.)

Ultimately this should return a list of points within the radius, sorted by distance.  It's a bit complex because the use at the time called for very high precision, so in this query the projection of the circle onto the plane of the Earth accounts for the **curvature of the Earth’s surface** and the **bulging at the equator**, derived from the WGS-84 ellipsoid model.  There may be a simpler model with less precision :)

Comment: That query will generate a full table scan, with a complex math calculation for every row. That is going to be very slow. At the very least, use an upper and lower bound on one of the dimensions, say the latitude, and index on that dimension. Much better, use spatial data types with a spatial index.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also look at installing the MySQL Spatial Extensions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html